# how to export object as of a defined type

Tags: typescript

I would like to restrict the type of exported function for my module

```
type PropertyRequest = ItemGetRequest | ItemUpdateRequest<Property>
type PropertyResponse = Property | ItemUpdateResponse<Property>

type PropertyHandlers = {[key: string]: Handler<PropertyRequest, PropertyResponse>}

export { propertyGet, propertyUpdate } as PropertyHandlers
```

but seems like syntax `export {...} as Type` is not correct or not supported in 3.4.1. How would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax support for type assertions in exports, you will have to declare a variable and export that:

```
const defaultExport: PropertyHandlers = { propertyGet, propertyUpdate };

export default defaultExport
```

Comment: but default export will not export them as object with default key while I need a plain object to be exported. My modules will be compiled and used with as ASW Appsync resolvers so I do not handle the way they import it.